# Blending Image with background in css

Tags: html, css

Here as you guys can see there is visible separation between the image and the background is there any way to kind of like blend the image with the background so that that separation is not visible.

[image]h

Comment: On the left hand side there is a border like separation.

Comment: Just export the image as semi-transparent PNG including that faded out background shadow, is there an issue with that? It would allow for any background, wouldn't even have to be a solid color, can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess You need to Use Overlay for the image.

Just wrap Image inside  and add the css to that div

```
.wrap_img:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: radial-gradient(transparent, white 90%, white 100%);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Reduce opacity as per your need.